# How to print on Chrome with website info (printed file URL)?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, url

I am trying to print [this pdf file](http://indico.cern.ch/getFile.py/access?contribId=56&sessionId=9&resId=0&materialId=slides&confId=179611) through Google Chrome. For administrative reasons I would like to prove on the printed page that this comes from a certain website.

How to print this document in Chrome in a way that at the page's footer the URL of the website will appear?

Comment: 1. You're not printing "from a website", you're just printing a file. Files don't carry any origin metadata. 2. Let's assume you can print that PDF with some origin info. How would you prove that you haven't simply embedded origin data in a forged file?

Comment: @gronostaj: Thank you very much for your comment. They just need my contribution with a proof that comes from a cern site. I don't even know what does "embedded origin data in a forged file" mean.

Comment: To put it simpler, imagine that you have that document printed and signed by a CERN employee. How would you prove that you haven't just forged the document and printed the signature instead of obtaining it legitimately? If you can print a "proof" on a regular printer, then you can print a fake proof too.

Comment: @gronostaj: I see what you mean. That's why I want the url to be visible. If someone has doubts, he can type the url in, in see the relevant document.

Comment: In internet explorer you can add custom header and footers ( custom text only).

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome:  my problem was solved by changing margins from "minimum" to custom.  Header/footer re-appeared.  sometimes I adjust the margins down, but didn't notice that I caused the header/footer to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

1. Print out the PDF.
2. Create a new Word document.
3. Add a header with the PDF's URL.
4. Print it on the same page as the PDF.

Done ;)

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what's wrong with this answer. I can't improve it unless I know what's there to improve.

Answer (score 2):

A rather late answer, but there is a sort-of workaround that doesn't involve editing PDFs or using a Word doc:

- Print out the PDF and put the page/s back in the printer
- Viewing the PDF in the Adobe Reader in Chrome, go *Hamburger menu > Print ...* and it should show as a blank page
- Select to add the URL header
- Print as many copies as there were pages in the original PDF, and the URL will be overlaid

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you print a regular webpage (HTML file), you get some options in the Google Chrome [print page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1379552?hl=en) dialog:

> - **Headers and footers:** Choose whether to include a default header and footer that display the date, page title, URL, and number of pages
>   printed.
> - **Two-sided:** Choose this option to print on both sides of the paper if you have a duplex printer.
> - **Print using system dialog (except Chrome OS):** Use your operating system's print functionality instead of Chrome's functionality to
>   print the page.

Selecting the **Headers and footers** would do exactly what you need to achieve - it will show the webpage URL in the footer (as well as some other data in the header and in the footer, as mentioned above).

However, when printing a **pdf** file in Chrome, you only get two options: **Fit to page** & **Two-Sided**. You can't include headers and footers in the pdf file.

So far I haven't found any simple workarounds to solve this. Using Adobe PDF viewer instead of Chrome's or using the default printer dialog won't help.

The only solution I found so far is to either download the pdf file to your computer (by right clicking the pdf page and clicking "Save as...") and edit it in a PDF manager/editor like Adobe Acrobat, or to [edit the pdf file online](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1680&bih=925&q=edit%20pdf%20online&oq=edit%20pdf%20online&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.142763.145576.0.145726.17.13.1.3.4.0.203.1362.7j5j1.13.0....0...1c.1.29.serp..2.15.1006.Cg09WlgmGu4), copy the URL of the pdf file, add it to the pdf file (where ever you want) and print it. Both will work.

Comment: This is no longer true: In the current version of Chrome you can include Headers & Footers when the destination is PDF.

Comment: The problem is that on the current version of Chrome, the URL is missing from the Headers & Footers, even when you print to paper.

Answer (score 1):

EDGE:
3 horizontal dots > print

print as pdf > more options > check box to add footer and header to show time stamp and url

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use drop box to do a screen shot and this includes the date and time on my PC.

So keyboard shortcuts are Ctrl plus " Prt Sc" ( print screen!) and voila! will save you an image with a date and time where you can then crop in Microsoft photo editor or similar id you wish to trim down and neaten up.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

This may work in chrome too

I use firefox ( if chrome does not work like this - open file in firefox)

while viewing file if you just do -  ctrl-p
you get minimal info

However if you go to firefox menu (at Top Right 3 bars)
and THEN go to print

it shows a print dialog box which is very different

It shows

Total # of pages in file and also shows each page if you want to scroll through

( you can decide that the last 3 pages in a 20 page file are junk and print only page 1-17)

ALL footer and headers are printed WITH

- website, Title of file (on each page )

AND it adds time date, page # etc (on each page )

Answer (score 0):

Click 3 small dot icon, select print, select more setting, select margin, select default on drop down menu...now you have url on your printed pdf. Goodluck